# Reverse video and loop 2 times ffmpeg

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I need to reverse the input video and concat it then the loop the output video twice. 
I was able to achieve reversing and concat it with original video using

`ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter_complex "[0:v]reverse,fifo[r];[0:v][r] concat=n=2:v=1 [v]" -map "[v]" output.mkv`

But i want to stream_loop it 3 times. And also i like to know, if there's any better ways to do it. The video will be a small one(4 seconds max.) and without audio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the first command,

`ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter_complex "[0:v]reverse,fifo[r];[0:v][r] concat=n=2:v=1 [v]" -map "[v]" output.mkv`

you can run

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop 2 -i output.mkv -c copy output3.mkv
```

To do it in one go,

`ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter_complex "[0:v]reverse,split=3[r1][r2][r3];[0:v][r1][0:v][r2][0:v][r3] concat=n=6:v=1[v]" -map "[v]" output.mkv`

With recent versions of ffmpeg, you shouldn't need fifo filters.

Comment: Thanks. I got another command to do this. But like to know which is faster and stable.

`ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter_complex "[0]reverse[r];[0][r]concat,loop=3:250,setpts=N/30/TB" output.mp4`

Comment: Using the stream loop after your original command is the fastest. My one-pass command doesn't require the user to know the frame count or framerate, so I prefer it.

Comment: okay. thanks. If you are using ffmpeg on Android can you suggest me any doc for it's integration. I've generated all *.so files for arm64-v8a, armeabi & armeabi-v7a, but don't know how to integrate it to Android.